# Cross Application Model/View(/Controller) with Qt

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, network-programming

I am trying to develop a cross application model/view scheme using Qt. What I mean attempting is to have:

Data: SQL Server

Model: Server Application

View/Controller: Client Application

This is for security reasons so that the Client App does not communicate directly with the server. Instead the communication between the model and the data server is handled via proxy Server App which runs on the same server as the database. Communication between the latter two is easy since Qt has the classes to handle it already and they are relatively easy to sub-class.

The problem for me is how to establish the connection between the model (based in the remote Server App) and the view (in local Client App).

I will present my ideas I gathered from researching the topic if it is the right direction but I would really appreciate some guidance. So first I will establish the network socket-based connection between the two apps. But what then? Is it possible to simply "link" the model in the Server App in the Client App as if they were part of the same app? Or should there be the model in the Client App as well and the connection would be used for synchronization between the two models? Or something different?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitly will have to implement some kind of protocoll. There is no benefit in security if you just link the complete model from server to client. More you will have a `local copy` in your applications cache for repesenting the data. You need to define what to sync and when to check for new data or send data back to the server. After that start implementing the most basic protocoll options and start sending some data across. On top of that start implementing any more features you need.